# Error while using SqlCommand multiple times

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I'm using SqlCommand for the function executeNONQuery() but it give me an error : 
There is already an open datareader associated with this command which must be closed first
I know I need to close it. so i used the dispode method, but it didnt work.
Anyone can help me?
Thank you!

here is some of the code :

```
                    Product pr = new Product();
                    pr.command.Dispose();
                    if ((t=(search(int.Parse(CatNum.Text))))!=null)
                    {
                        if (t == "Float")
                        {                            
                            pr.command.Dispose();
                            pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("select amount from storage where catalogNumber={0}", int.Parse(CatNum.Text));
                            SqlDataReader reader = pr.command.ExecuteReader();
                            float currAmount = 0;
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                currAmount = float.Parse(reader["amount"].ToString());
                            }

                            pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("Update storage set catalogNumber={0} amount = {1} where catalogNumber={0}", int.Parse(CatNum.Text), float.Parse(Amount.Text) + currAmount);                            
                            pr.command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            CatNum.Text = string.Empty;
                            CatNum.Focus();
                            sb.AppendFormat("<div class='alert alert-success'>Adding the product was successfull</div>");
                        }
                        else if (int.TryParse(Amount.Text, out q) && t == "Integer")
                        {                           
                            pr.command.Dispose();
                            pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("select amount from storage where catalogNumber={0}", int.Parse(CatNum.Text));
                            SqlDataReader reader = pr.command.ExecuteReader();
                            int currAmount = 0;
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                currAmount = int.Parse(reader["amount"].ToString());
                            }

                            pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("Update storage set catalogNumber={0} amount = {1} where catalogNumber={0}", int.Parse(CatNum.Text), int.Parse(Amount.Text) + currAmount);
                            pr.command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            CatNum.Text = string.Empty;
                            CatNum.Focus();
                            sb.AppendFormat("<div class='alert alert-success'>Adding the product was successfull</div>");
                        }
```

Comment: Don't reuse the command, initiate a new one, with a new connection. .NET does it's own connection pooling so you are not gaining anything by reusing the objects.

Comment: Well, based off that error message, it sounds like you need to do `reader.Close();` before attempting to re-use the SqlCommand object, but without seeing your code, that's just a guess

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you start your second query.

`reader.Close();`

Comment: Did you put the code in my answer after while loop? The `SqlCommand` object may not. But the `SqlDataReader` most certainly does. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should use try-catch-finally exception management, to avoid unhandled exceptions on your code.

If the command fails, either because the connection dropped or simply because the query is incorrect, the reader will not close because it won't reach that part of the code.

Try to put your code like this:

```
    Product pr = new Product();
             try {
                    pr.command.Dispose();
                    if ((t=(search(int.Parse(CatNum.Text))))!=null)
                    {
                        if (t == "Float")
                        {                            
                            pr.command.Dispose();
                            pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("select amount from storage where catalogNumber={0}", int.Parse(CatNum.Text));
                            SqlDataReader reader = pr.command.ExecuteReader();
                            float currAmount = 0;
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                currAmount = float.Parse(reader["amount"].ToString());
                            }
                            reader.close;
                            pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("Update storage set catalogNumber={0} amount = {1} where catalogNumber={0}", int.Parse(CatNum.Text), float.Parse(Amount.Text) + currAmount);                            
                            pr.command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            CatNum.Text = string.Empty;
                            CatNum.Focus();
                            sb.AppendFormat("<div class='alert alert-success'>Adding the product was successfull</div>");
                        }
                        else if (int.TryParse(Amount.Text, out q) && t == "Integer")
                        {                           
                            pr.command.Dispose();
                            pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("select amount from storage where catalogNumber={0}", int.Parse(CatNum.Text));
                            SqlDataReader reader = pr.command.ExecuteReader();
                            int currAmount = 0;
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                currAmount = int.Parse(reader["amount"].ToString());
                            }
                            reader.close;
                            pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("Update storage set catalogNumber={0} amount = {1} where catalogNumber={0}", int.Parse(CatNum.Text), int.Parse(Amount.Text) + currAmount);
                            pr.command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            CatNum.Text = string.Empty;
                            CatNum.Focus();
                            sb.AppendFormat("<div class='alert alert-success'>Adding the product was successfull</div>");
                        }
}
         catch (SqlException sqlex) {
             // do your thing when sql exception pops out }
         catch (Exception ex) {
             // do your thing when any exception pops out }
         finally {
          reader.close; }
```

This will close the reader even if an exception comes out.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems with this code I don't really know where to begin.

Without over complicating anything and keeping it as generic as possible I'd suggest scrapping your product class, it just looks like a holder for your SqlCommand, and based on your usage this is not very helpful anyway, without even considering the problems with this approach.

You would be much better off using a new SqlCommand and connection each time, it is really not that much code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("CommandText", connection))
{
    connection.Open();
    // User your command here
}
```

Next don't use `string.Format` to build your queries, use proper parameterised queries, you will benefit from type safety and query plan caching, as well as removing risk of sql injection.

So instead of

```
command.CommandText = string.Format("select amount from storage where catalogNumber={0}", int.Parse(CatNum.Text));
```

You would use:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT Amount FROM Storage WHERE CatalogNumber = @CatalogNumber";
int catNum = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(CatNum.Text, out catNum))
{
    // Do something to handle an invalid input
}
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatalogNumber", catNum);
```

The next problem is here:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    currAmount = float.Parse(reader["amount"].ToString());
}
```

Here, there is two problems, the first is unnecessary casting (you can just use `reader.GetFloat()`, but more importantly you will iterate the whole data set only to assign the value in the last row to your variable. If your dataset only has one row, then this isn't really a problem, but you'd be just as well using `ExecuteScalar` to get a single value.

```
currAmount = float.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Finally, you are not actually doing anything in this update:

```
Update storage set catalogNumber={0} amount = {1} where catalogNumber={0}
```

You have just read `amount` from the same table, and `SET CatalogNumber = 1 WHERE CatalogNumber = 1` is doing nothing.

I can't really work out why you are handling floats and integers in two separate blocks, but it looks like your code could be cut down to:

```
int catNum = 0;
if (!int.TryParse(CatNum.Text, out catNum))
{
    // Do something to handle an invalid input
}
float currAmount = 0;
using (var connection = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Amount FROM Storage WHERE CatalogNumber = @CatalogNumber", connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatalogNumber", catNum);
    connection.Open();
    currAmount = float.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
}

CatNum.Text = string.Empty;
CatNum.Focus();
sb.AppendFormat("<div class='alert alert-success'>Adding the product was successfull</div>");
```